# Cumulative value counts of categorical data, with group by

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

In my data frame, I have a text column `group` with the group name, and column `drop_week`, holding a categorical value in range [1,4]. I want to store, for each group, the cumulative count of values 1 to 4 of drop week. I'm doing this:

```
drop_data = all_data[['group', 'drop_week']].groupby('group')['drop_week'] \
    .value_counts().unstack().transpose().fillna(0).cumsum().transpose()
```

and it works. But since it took me 2 hours of googling to come up with this solution, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Please provide a few columns as a sample input ([mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to create the frequency table. Then use `cumsum(axis=1)` to compute the cumulative sum across each row:

```
pd.crosstab(index=all_data['group'], columns=all_data['drop_week']).cumsum(axis=1)
# drop_week   1   2   3   4
# group                    
# 0          12  17  21  27
# 1           7  13  18  25
# 2           9  14  22  26
# 3           5  11  16  22
```

which agrees with

```
drop_data = (all_data[['group', 'drop_week']].groupby('group')['drop_week']
             .value_counts().unstack().transpose().fillna(0).cumsum().transpose())
# drop_week   1   2   3   4
# group                    
# 0          12  17  21  27
# 1           7  13  18  25
# 2           9  14  22  26
# 3           5  11  16  22
```

---

The setup I used for this was:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 100
all_data = pd.DataFrame({'group':np.random.randint(4, size=N),
                         'drop_week':np.random.randint(1,5, size=N)})

drop_data = (all_data[['group', 'drop_week']].groupby('group')['drop_week']
             .value_counts().unstack().transpose().fillna(0).cumsum().transpose())
```